# PHP $_POST function x() in echo

Tags: php

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong in this way? There's a three different radio buttons with selections and different inputs. When selected radio button in example 2, then input text, submitting form - reloads, generating outputs properly, shows last selected radio button, but shows 1st button fields. Attaching a screenshot for better understanding.

Code:

```
<form name="form" id="form" method="POST" action=""
        enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <div class="form-row">

            <div>
                <div class="f hide" id="div1">
                Option nr. 1
                <label></label> <input type="text" style="text-transform: uppercase;" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}" placeholder="Letters"  class="form-control" name="txt_input" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['txt_input']) ? $_POST['txt_input'] : '' ?>" maxlength="3" >
                <label></label> <input type="text" placeholder="Digits" pattern="\d{3}"  style="text-transform: uppercase;" class="form-control" name="num_input" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['num_input']) ? $_POST['num_input'] : '' ?>" maxlength="3" >
                    </div>
                    
                    
                    
                    <div class="sl box hide" id="div2">
                    Option nr. 2
                <label></label> <input type="text" style="text-transform: uppercase;" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}"  placeholder="Letters"  class="form-control" name="txt_inputsl" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['txt_inputsl']) ? $_POST['txt_inputsl'] : '' ?>" maxlength="3" >
                <label></label> <input type="text" style="text-transform: uppercase;"  pattern="\d{3}"  placeholder="Digits"  class="form-control" name="num_inputsl" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['num_inputsl']) ? $_POST['num_inputsl'] : '' ?>" maxlength="3" >
                    </div>
                    
                    
                    
                    
               <div class="s box hide" id="div3">
               Option nr. 3
                <label></label> <input type="text" style="text-transform: uppercase;"   placeholder="Digits" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]+"  class="form-control" name="txt_input_" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['txt_input_']) ? $_POST['txt_input_'] : '' ?>" maxlength="6" >
                
            </div>
            <br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="check" onclick="show1();" value="f" <?php if($_POST['check'] == 'f') { print ' checked="checked"'; } ?> > Option nr. 1</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="check" onclick="show2();" value="sl" <?php if($_POST['check'] == 'sl') { print ' checked="checked"'; } ?> >Option nr. 2</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="check" onclick="show3();" value="s" <?php if($_POST['check'] == 's') { print ' checked="checked"'; } ?> >Option nr. 3</label>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="button-row">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Generate">
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
    function show1(){
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display ='block';
  document.getElementById('div2').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('div3').style.display ='none';
}   
function show2(){
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('div2').style.display ='block';
  document.getElementById('div3').style.display ='none';
}
function show3(){
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('div2').style.display ='none';
  document.getElementById('div3').style.display ='block';
}

    </script>
```

[image]

It seems like after submint - checking right radio button, but by function - stays on first option. Tried to use $_POST['show1()'] in echo value togheder with checking value - but didn't worked. Obviously I'm missing something, but searched for similar solutions - didn't found right way for that.
Appreciate for any responses!

Comment: In forms make sure to have unique name attribute of the checkboxes, all the name attributes inside a form should be unique. Also to access a field value use have to use $_POST['name'] that is for your case $_POST['check'].

Comment: Tried to give for them unique values, like check, check1 and check2 - changed whole code, but still heading with same issue :/

Answer (score 1):

Solved my issue and adding some code which I've used for.

For my radio buttons added id's and then added a .js function which checking is radio button checked, if it's true - does the trick, if it's not - does something else.

In this code:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="check" onclick="show1();" value="f" <?php if($_POST['check'] == 'f') { print ' checked="checked"'; } ?> > Option nr. 1</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="check" onclick="show2();" value="sl" <?php if($_POST['check'] == 'sl') { print ' checked="checked"'; } ?> >Option nr. 2</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="check" onclick="show3();" value="s" <?php if($_POST['check'] == 's') { print ' checked="checked"'; } ?> >Option nr. 3</label>
```

I changed to:

```
  <label><input type="radio" id="one" name="check" onclick="show1();" value="f" <?php if($_POST['check'] == 'f') { print ' checked="checked"'; } ?> > Option nr. 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" id="two" name="check" onclick="show2();" value="sl" <?php if($_POST['check'] == 'sl') { print ' checked="checked"'; } ?> >Option nr. 2</label>
<label><input type="radio" id="three" name="check" onclick="show3();" value="s" <?php if($_POST['check'] == 's') { print ' checked="checked"'; } ?> >Option nr. 3</label>
```

Then added new function with checking by selected radio button:

```
if(document.getElementById('one').checked) {
  
     document.getElementById('div1').style.display ='block';
     document.getElementById('div2').style.display ='none';
     document.getElementById('div3').style.display ='none';

}else if(document.getElementById('two').checked) {
      
      document.getElementById('div1').style.display ='none';
      document.getElementById('div2').style.display ='block';
      document.getElementById('div3').style.display ='none';

} else if(document.getElementById('three').checked) {
      
      document.getElementById('div1').style.display ='none';
      document.getElementById('div2').style.display ='none';
      document.getElementById('div3').style.display ='block';
}
```

Without this js function it was only checking radio button, but shows only first field until you clicking any other radio button. This function checks is any of them checked, if it's true = some kind function.
P.S. `<?php if($_POST['name'] == 'value') { print ' checked="checked"'; } ?>` is necessary in radio button parameters.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

on your code

```
<label>
        <input type="radio" name="check" onclick="show1();" value="f" <?php if($_POST['check'] == 'f') { print ' checked="checked"'; } ?> > Option nr. 1
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="check" onclick="show2();" value="sl" <?php if($_POST['check'] == 'sl') { print ' checked="checked"'; } ?> >Option nr. 2
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="check" onclick="show3();" value="s" <?php if($_POST['check'] == 's') { print ' checked="checked"'; } ?> >Option nr. 3
</label>
```

change to

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="check" onclick="show1();" value="f" <?=(isset($_POST['check']) && $_POST['check'] == 'f')?'checked="checked"':"" ?> > Option nr. 1
</label>
<label>
   <input type="radio" name="check" onclick="show2();" value="sl" <?=(isset($_POST['check']) && $_POST['check'] == 'sl')?'checked="checked"':"" ?> >Option nr. 2
</label>
<label>
   <input type="radio" name="check" onclick="show3();" value="s" <?=(isset($_POST['check']) && $_POST['check'] == 's')?'checked="checked"':"" ?> >Option nr. 3
 </label>
```

Comment: Actually does the same trick like mine, and still getting same result :/

Comment: take a look at this [link](https://php5.racoontech.my.id/test/), is the result still the same?

Comment: Appreciate for that, about "remember" input for field - it's okay, just I'm heading with remember which field to show only I'm struggling. If selected radio is option 3, after submit should show only option 3 field, not all of them :/